# pandas.isna() vs pandas.DataFrame.isna()

Tags: pandas, similar-documents

I've seen the two documentation pages for [pandas.isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) but the difference is still unclear to me.  Could someone explain the difference to me using examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They call the same underlying method, so there is no functional difference.

Calling the dataframe member function is preferred for OOP patterns, but there are many redundancies/aliases in pandas and python in general.

---

In case you are curious, here is how the source code breaks down (it is a mess).

The DataFrame (`pandas/core/frame.py`) method is simply:

```
def isna(self):
    return super().isna()
```

Where DataFrame extends NDFrame (implemented in `pandas/core/generic.py`). NDFrame subsequently invokes:

```
def isna(self):
    return isna(self).__finalize__(self)
```

Which was imported here:

```
from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isna, notna
```

In `pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py`:

```
def isna(obj):
    return _isna(obj)
```

The `_isna` function is later aliased as `_isna = _isna_new` because there is a deprecated method `_isna_old(obj)`.

The `_isna_new(obj)` function then performs the logic operations:

```
def _isna_new(obj)
    if is_scalar(obj):
        return libmissing.checknull(obj)
    # hack (for now) because MI registers as ndarray
    elif isinstance(obj, ABCMultiIndex):
        raise NotImplementedError("isna is not defined for MultiIndex")
    elif isinstance(obj, type):
        return False
    elif isinstance(
        obj,
        (
            ABCSeries,
            np.ndarray,
            ABCIndexClass,
            ABCExtensionArray,
            ABCDatetimeArray,
            ABCTimedeltaArray,
        ),
    ):
        return _isna_ndarraylike(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, ABCGeneric):
        return obj._constructor(obj._data.isna(func=isna))
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return _isna_ndarraylike(np.asarray(obj, dtype=object))
    elif hasattr(obj, "__array__"):
        return _isna_ndarraylike(np.asarray(obj))
    else:
        return obj is None
```

Ultimately, the DataFrame method passes itself as a parameter to the same function that you call with `pandas.isna()`.